# etc/passwd cannot be found

Tags: etc, passwd-file

I can't find the `etc/passwd` file on my Ubuntu computer. I know I shouldn't try to mess with it now, but when I was I couldn't find it. Yet I can still access my computer.

Did they hide it in the 14.04 version? Should I be worried?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `stat /etc/passwd`.

Answer (score 1):

You refer to "etc/passwd" - note the missing "/" at the beginning.
Since you repeat this path twice with the same "mistake" - perhaps it is not a typo but the source of your problem. So my answer is relevant if indeed you miss the "/" at the beginning:

"passwd" is located under the absolute path "/etc/". If you look for "etc/passwd" you are actually looking for that file in the *relative* path to your current working directory. Assuming your current directory is not the root (/) then you are looking at the wrong place (your_current_dir/etc/passwd).

Comment: even with /etc/passwd still not found, thought it was implied i'd tried it as root or user, sorry. ill be more explicit for now on.